# Having Error While iterate through 2D Array using Float

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3

I am using an 2D array to store all the coordinates and I would like to assign each of the coordinate into a `CGPoint` function but I am getting this error:

> cannot subscript a value of type inout[[Float]]

Below is my Code:

```
        var entryPoint: [[Float]] = [[130.6,52.3],[167.5,52.1],[204.5,51.91],[243.6,48.91],[281.16,48.75],[167.5,67.41],[204.5,67.91],[243.6,68.5],[281.16,69.16]]

        for var x in 0..<entryPoint.count
        {
            for var y in 0..<entryPoint[x].count
            {
                print(entryPoint[x][y])
                let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: entryPoint[x][y],y: entryPoint[x][y]), radius: CGFloat(0.5), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
                let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
                shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.8
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading issue is that `CGPoint(x:y:)` needs `CGFloat` as argument and you are currently passing `Float` value convert `Float` to `CGFloat` will reduce that error.

```
var entryPoint: [[Float]] = [[130.6,52.3],[167.5,52.1],[204.5,51.91],[243.6,48.91],[281.16,48.75],[167.5,67.41],[204.5,67.91],[243.6,68.5],[281.16,69.16]]
for entry in Array(entryPoint.dropFirst()) {
        print(entry[0])
        print(entry[1])
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(entry[0]),y: CGFloat(entry[1]), radius: CGFloat(0.5), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.8
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can also make array of type `[[CGFloat]]` instead of `[[Float]]` that will also remove this error.

Comment: i have change the array type to CGFLoat and it fix the error...but when i assigning value why the CGPoint X and Y value are the same?

Comment: @NgHsiaoQin Check the edited answer, You don't need second for loop

Comment: @NiravD Do not force to upvote your answer also do not copy my answer with your modification.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I haven't force upvoted answer, answer is already up voted also I haven't copy your answer you are looping with `enumerated` and that is unnecessary as you are not even using index also I can also say the same you are copy my answer as of I have already suggested about array changes in my Note before you posted answer

Comment: I took 3 minutes to write my answer but I am not a copy of you I have seen your comment for forcing for upvoting now the comment was deleted by you also I am not edited my answer as you after seeing my answer.

Comment: He upvoted my answer but you do the unnecessary debate for upvoting your answer..

Comment: And at the end for the enumerated, I wrote "copy my answer with your modification"

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani OP up voted  both the answer and then he accepted my​ answer twice and up accepted it again that's why I asked op about accepting answer. There is a difference between up vote and accepting answer but you don't know that because it looks like you haven't accepted any solution from your asked question

Comment: Is there anyway to assign the CGPoint start from the second row from the entryPoint array?

Comment: @NgHsiaoQin you want to ignore the first object of array and want to go from second ?

Comment: Yup. i want to go from second

Comment: @NgHsiaoQin Use dropFirst with array for that check the edited answer

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to access to next row in the loop?

Comment: Don't get you can you edit your questions with some example.

Comment: is lets say i want to compare current row value with the next row want

Comment: @NgHsiaoQin and what you want to compare here ? It will better if you edit your question with some example of what you want

Answer (score 2):

Simply Change the Type `Float` to `CGFloat` :

```
var entryPoint: [[CGFloat]] = [[130.6,52.3],[167.5,52.1],[204.5,51.91],[243.6,48.91],[281.16,48.75],[167.5,67.41],[204.5,67.91],[243.6,68.5],[281.16,69.16]]
```

Also, you can iterate like this :

```
for (index,value) in entryPoint.enumerated(){
    print("Zero",value[0])
    print("One",value[1])
}
```